# How can I see conversion result of Google Ads on Google Analytics

Tags: google-tag-manager

)

For a few weeks, I have had really the difficulty of understanding the system between three platforms* for conversion tracking and tracking conversion results

- Google Analytics - Google Ads - GTM(Google Tag Manager)

First of all,

- Our team wants to track the conversion
- Set up GA/GTM global code on our web
- completed set-up of data layers for an event(transactionComplete*) tracking

  - We need to track only the 'transaction' through ads as a financial company
- completed linking google ads with google analytics

We have two types of transaction conversion

1. Google Analytics - Goals / Website and Transaction Page URL-based one
2. Google Ads - Conversions - GTM connected

Two of them are recording normally when I check google ads' conversion page

- I can see results(traffic/behaviors/event) of GA Goals on Google Analytics
  however; I can't see Google ads' conversion results in detail

Where/how can I see google ads' conversion results on Google Analytics?

I herby attache some images of them for your understanding

1. Google Analtyics Goal - transactionComplete
   [Google Analtyics Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiZMC.png)
2. Google Ads Conversion Result - transactionComplete - GTM connected
   [Google Ads Conversion Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI4pU.png)
3. our GTM Setting - [GTM Setting - Google Ads Conversion Tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBdtt.png)
4. GTM Setting - [GTM Setting - Event/Data Layer's data to GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHLkP.png)

Thank you for reading my question.

I'm struggling ... please help ㅠㅠ

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean "can't see Google ads' conversion results". Is it the conversion how many times or how much value?

Comment: Thank you for your comment sincerely. 

It means that I can't find the detail of the google ads' conversion data(as for overseas transaction)

I created a conversion in Google Ads and get it connected with tag through GTM(Custom Event Tag). 

So, every time the transaction receipt page' comes out on our Website, It will track our event. 

It has been recorded more than 500 transactions until now.

However, I can't find any detailed results (such as visit/session/traffic) of the same figure in Google Analytics.